# VB6 code to find windows OS version

Tags: windows, vb6

I am using [OSVERSIONINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724834%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to check the OS in my vb6 application. But i am not able differentiate between windows 7 and windows server 2008 R2 because they have same version number,dwMajorVersion and dwMinorVersion. So how to differentiate between these. I think it can be done in vb.net using some other method. But how it can be done in vb6?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Xearinox noted in the above comment, `OSVERSIONINFOEX` returns more information.

In particular, you can examine `wProductType` to determine whether `VER_NT_WORKSTATION` (0x0000001) is set or not. If it is, the machine is running a client OS, otherwise, server.

The chart in the remarks section of the [OSVERSIONINFO MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724834%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) even has a column which points out detecting the various OS's using that struct item.

Comment: hi lynn In my vb6 code both windows 7 and windows server 2008 r2 are returning wProductType as O. why does it happen?

Comment: @winman O or 0? You'll have to provide some code for anyone to be able to answer your question.

Comment: Sorry it was returning 0. I was able to correct the error as i was using OSVERSIONINFO before so i defined osinfo.dwOSVersionInfoSize = 148(where i declared osinfo as "Dim osinfo As OSVERSIONINFOEX") when i changed it to OSVERSIONINFOEX i didnt change dwOSVersionInfoSize , so it was returning 0 for all cases as wProductType was byte. Then i changed it to osinfo.dwOSVersionInfoSize = 156 and everything worked fine

Answer (score 3):

Right Click On Tool Bar > Components And Add > Microsoft SysControl 6.0.
Double Click The SysInfo Button to Add on Form and use this code

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim HancyRockz as string
    HancyRockz = "OsVersion :- " & SysInfo1.OSVersion & " / Built " & SysInfo1.OSBuild
    Text1.Text=HancyRockz
End Sub
```